# HTTP basic authorization in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, http-headers, basic-authentication

I need to send Username and password in header of the request and get some json as response using HTTP basic authorization. 
I have set username and password in the controller using

http_basic_authenticate_with name: "dhh", password: "secret", except: :index

how should i send them using http header?
someone please help

Answer (score 0):

Well I am not sure if I understood your question correctly, but you can bypass http basic auth like this:

> https://username:password@domain.com

And after that just return data you need in your controller.